# TYPO3 9.5.15 with gridelements and t3sbootstrap not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

I have a new TYPO3 9.5.15 installation and added gridelements 9.5.0 and t3sbootstrap 4.4.5 to make content elements with 3 columns in a own 1 column backendlayout which is defined in PageTsConfig.

In older TYPO3 versions, this is working fine (i.e TYPO3 7) but in TYPO3 9 I get the following error in FE:

Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->three_columns" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/Three_columns.html). The following paths were checked: 
xxx/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/, xxx/typo3conf/ext/gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/, xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/, xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Templates/, ,

I've double checked and can confirm, that both, gridelements and t3sbootstrap are included in the roottemplate of the website.

As far as I found out, the templates are available in xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Templates/Gridelements/
but are called ThreeColumns.html

Has anyone an idee what causes the error and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first look it seems that there are 2 problems with your combination here:

The message "Standard->three_columns" points to a wrong static template, so I guess you included the new DataProcessing static of Gridelements, while t3sbootstrap depends on the old Plugin and USER based static.

The root path xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Templates/Gridelements/ is missing in your setup.

At a second look it might even be enough to change the Gridelements static, since t3sbootstrap takes care of the root path based on that setup.

Comment: BTW: The Plugin and USER based static got deprecated with Gridelements 10 and will be removed with Gridelements 11.

Comment: So that I get you right. I have 3 different static templates from gridelements that I can include:
1. Gridelements
2. Gridelements w/DataProcessing
3. Gridelements (deprecated beta version)

Comment: I had included number 1 and 2.
replace number 2 with number 3 ends in an error too:
The Fluid template files "Main.html", "Main",
"xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content/Main.html", 
"xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content/Main", 
"xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main.html", 
"xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main", 
"xxx/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main.html", 
"xxx/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main" could not be loaded.

Comment: You should never include more than one Gridelements static at once. 1 is the way to go, since t3sbootstrap does not work with DataProcessing but with the good old USER plugin.

2 would be recommended for anything new you are building today, which is not based on another extension with dependencies to 1.

3 is just there for people who used it before 2 came out, has been deprecated with Gridelements 9 and was removed with Gridelements 10.

Comment: Thanl you for this explenation. Now I've just included 1. But sadly the error still exists

Comment: It seems that you did not include the template of t3sbootstrap then, since this will translate the old template names to the new ones: 

https://github.com/t3solution/t3sbootstrap/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElement/Gridelements.typoscript#L35

Comment: The template of t3sbootstrap is included. I've also played around with the order too. Same error: The Fluid template files "Main.html", "Main", "xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content/Main.html", "xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content/Main", "xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main.html", "xxx/typo3conf/ext/t3sbootstrap/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main", "xxx/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main.html", "xxx/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Main" could not be loaded.

Comment: so are you sure, that you did not overwrite the root paths and/or the frontend output of t3sbootstrap within your own site package or another kind of frontend extension or frontend template?

Comment: I'm sure that my sitepackege doen't interfear with this configuration. However I'm not sure if this error occures, bcause of the T3SB Configuration I made as I tried to solve the error. But at the moment I have no clue how to get rid of this T3SB Configuration

Comment: So could you try to remove any of your custom configuration to check, if both, Gridelements and t3sbootstrap, are working correctly?

Comment: I found out, that it had to be some configuration in my sitepackage. But t3sbootstrap threw an other error even without my sitepackage. I replaced t3sbootstrap now with pp_gridelements. Now the FE works fine. Thanks again for youre patience and help.